# How can I create new categorical variable by grouping character variable in SAS

Tags: sas, character, grouping, categories, categorization

I am trying to create a new categorical variables by grouping character variables. This is what I did so far but it came up with no observations:

```
data want_newvar;
set have_oldvar;
if (oldvar= 'A1') or ('A2'= oldvar)or ('A3'= oldvar) or ('A4'= oldvar) or ('A5'= oldvar) or ('A6'= oldvar)or ('A7'= oldvar)or ('A8'=oldvar) or ('A9'=oldvar) or ('A10'=oldvar) then newvar= 'cat_name';

run;
```

Comment: What do you mean by no observations? Your approach is correct but you may want to include your log so we can see what SAS says is wrong. Your code is inefficent as well, you should be using IN instead of multiple OR.  `if oldvar in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', ..., 'A10') then newvar='A1 to A10';`

Comment: This is what the log said: WARNING: The data set want_newvar may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0
         observations and 20 variables.
WARNING: Data set want_newvar was not replaced because this step was stopped.

Comment: That's a warning not an error. Please post the exact log, the log indicates where in your code the error is, it could be the wrong input data set, you're referencing a variable that doesn't exist because you're using a label not a name or a hundred other small issues like forgetting a semicolon. Without the log, your code is correct so this means your logic is wrong for some reason and that's as much as we can say.

Comment: What was log part **above** the WARNING ? Was it something like `                                         -
                                         386
                                         200
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

18     run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.`   If so, your code might have 'smart quotes' in it instead single quotes (copy and paste from Word or PDF could  be where smart quotes came from) .

Answer (score 0):

You're better off with a format rather than a series of if/then/else statements. You can then use it easily in other steps.

```
proc format;
   value $myformatname
        'A1' = 'New Category'
        'A2' = 'New Category'
        'A3' = 'New Category'
   ;
run;

data want;
    oldcat = 'A1';
    newcat = put(oldcat, $myformatname.);
run;
```